# Xamarin Android VOIP Push notification handling

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, voip, voip-android

We are developing an enterprise application using Voice over IP technology with CrossGeek's Firebase Push Notification NuGet. For VOIP calls, we need to implement a cross platform solution for firing up the application for an incoming voice call. On iOS the solution is the VOIP push, which is done by implementing PKPushKit. Unfortunately we are stucked with Android. We want to Start the activity when a specific payloaded notification comes, or just display two buttons for the notification one for decline, and one for accept the incoming call. As I see, this notification plugin that we are using is not supporting the terminated application custom notification handling. I've found on the StackOverFlow, that we need to extend a custom service from the FirebasePushNotificationService, but it seems this service will catch all the notifications from the NuGet package used to handle notifications. Any ideas how to handle terminated application VOIP pushes especially for Android platform?
Also one more question to mention, what is the right method to handle VOIP Notifications? Requesting Screen awake, Dismissing keyguard and Starting the activity? Or implement something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to implement Push notification handling on Android by our own. You have to derive from FirebaseMessagingService, implement the interface. It will run as a service, which can handle your Push Notifs. But you have to manually implement the displaying of the notifications to the statusbar, or starting the activity.

VOIP Notifications require priority set to the highest.

Comment: Hi, i have the same situation and not able to bring fullscreen intent on notification bar. I tried with telecomManager.AddNewIncomingCall but it will first open our app and then shows the incoming call. I want to have similar experience like skype, team and whatsup does on Android. Can you please share some of your code or direction?